# Is my server using Legacy BIOS or UEFI?

Tags: linux, uefi, bios

I am little confused about something. I have a server on Digital Ocean, I want to know either BIOS or UEFI used for system startup.

I have tried following things:

```bsh
root@debian:~$ dmidecode -t 0
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: DigitalOcean
        Version: 20171212
        Release Date: 12/12/2017
        Address: 0xE8000
        Runtime Size: 96 kB
        ROM Size: 64 kB
        Characteristics:
                BIOS characteristics not supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.0

root@debian:/~$ efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

root@debian:/~$ ls -l /sys/firmware/efi
ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory
```

It looks like BIOS is used. But there is also `efi` directory in `/boot`.

```bsh
root@debian:/~$ ls -l /boot/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    16384 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Mar 30 18:48 grub
```

Beside that, when I looked at the disk partion table, it is GPT. I knew GPT is not used with BIOS, at least not prefered. Also disk has EFI system partition.

```bsh
root@debian:/mnt$ fdisk -l /dev/vda
Disk /dev/vda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 72FE8E7C-20D9-2A4A-8AFF-75948771F0DA

Device      Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/vda1  262144 167772126 167509983 79.9G Linux filesystem
/dev/vda14   2048      8191      6144    3M BIOS boot
/dev/vda15   8192    262143    253952  124M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

What I am missing? How can I be sure which one is used on that system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root@debian:/~$ efibootmgr
EFI variables are not supported on this system.

root@debian:/~$ ls -l /sys/firmware/efi
ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory
```

So, legacy BIOS, not EFI.

> But there is also efi directory in /boot.

Doesn't matter, your Linux harddisk image can have one just in case. Only because it's present doesn't mean it got used.

> I knew GPT is not used with BIOS, at least not prefered.

GPT can boot with legacy BIOS just fine. Again, if you have an image that's made both for legacy BIOS and EFI, you'll have GPT and an EFI partition.